# How can i add delay for progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `html-5` progress bar and the values for progress bar has been passed from `JQuery`.
I want to delay the progress bar to get the progress values slowly.

Now it is getting the progress quickly.I want to get the progress smooth and slowly

How can i do this?

Here is what i have tried

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
for ( var i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) {
  document.getElementById('MyProgress').value = i; 
}
}),4000;
</script>
</head>
<body>
<progress id="MyProgress" value="0" max="100">
</progress>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use jQuery animate function, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/maximgladkov/H5wXj/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#MyProgress').animate({ value: 100 }, 10000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are likely to do like this:

```
setInterval(function(){
for ( var i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) {
  document.getElementById('MyProgress').value = i; 
}
},4000);
```

Answer (score 0):

USe `setTimeout`:

```
function setProgress(value){
    document.getElementById('MyProgress').value = value;
    if(value<=100){
       setTimeout(function(){
          setProgress(value++);
       },1000);
    }

}

$(document).ready(function(){
       setProgress(1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = 1;
function progressBar() {
    if(count > 100) {
        return;
    }
    document.getElementById('MyProgress').value = count++;
    setTimeout(function(){
        progressBar();
    }, 100)

}
```